# Print full text from a textarea

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm printing a form. The problem I have is when the text of the textarea field is large, when printing it does not print the whole text. I have the following code, to create the form and print:

```js
success: function(result){
  $.ajax({  
        url:"comp_den.php",  
        method:"POST",
        cache: false,                           
        dataType:"json",  
        success:function(data){
                  
            $(".insdenuncia").click(function(){
                $("#s1").hide();
            });
            $(".insdenuncia").click(function(){
                $("#s2").show();
            });
                  
            var linha = ``;

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        Denuncia = data[i][3];
        
        linha += `<div class="form-group form-message">
                                <textarea class="form-control acerto2 acerto4 area">${Denuncia}</textarea>
                                <label class="acerto2">Digite a sua denúncia</label>
                                </div>`;
                  } 


                  $('#s1').hide();
                  $('#s2').show();
                  $("#comprovativo").html(linha);
                  
                  $(document)
                      .on('keyup input keypress keydown change', '.area', function(e) {
                      var tamanhoMin =  $(this).attr('rows') * $(this).css('line-height').replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, '');

                      var novoTamanho = this.scrollHeight + parseFloat($(this).css("borderTopWidth")) + parseFloat($(this).css("borderBottomWidth"));
                      if (tamanhoMin > novoTamanho) novoTamanho = tamanhoMin;
                      $(this).css({'height': novoTamanho});
                  });

                  $(".area")
                      .delay(0)
                      .show(0, function() {
                      var el = $(this);
                      setTimeout(function () {
                          el.trigger('keyup');
                      }, 100);        
                  });

              }

document.getElementById("btnPrintt1").onclick = function () {
        printElement(document.getElementById("printThhis1")); 
    }
    
    function printElement(elem) {
    
        var domClone = elem.cloneNode(true);
        
        var $printSection = document.getElementById("printSection");
        
        if (!$printSection) {
            var $printSection = document.createElement("div");
            $printSection.id = "printSection";
            document.body.appendChild($printSection);
        }
        console.log($printSection);
        $printSection.innerHTML = "";
        $printSection.appendChild(domClone);
        window.print();
    
    }
```

```css
@media screen {
  #printSection {
    display: none !important;
  }       
}

@media print {
  #btnPrintt1{
  display: none !important;
  }
  .acerto4{
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #printSection { 
    left:0 !important;
    top:0 !important;
  }
  .pagebreak { page-break-before: always; }
}
```

```html
<form class="main__form" role="form" id="comprovativo">

</form>
<div class="text-center" style="margin-top: 4%;">
  <button type="button" class=" btn btn-get" id="btnPrintt1"><span><i class="pe-7s-print"></i> Comprovativo</span></button>
</div>
```

I already put the scroll bar to hide, but if the text is large when printing, after a certain height the text is hidden. Can you help?

Comment: One simple solution is in jquery take the text from the textarea put it into a div and just delete the textarea.

Comment: Why have you started your JS snippet with incompleteness `success: function(result){`. Could you please create a [mcve] - if relevant?

Comment: Curious why you add two click event handlers (both will fire in order)
            `$(".insdenuncia").click(function(){
                $("#s1").hide();
            });
            $(".insdenuncia").click(function(){
                $("#s2").show();
            });` when it could just be one `$(".insdenuncia").click(function(){
                $("#s1").hide();
                $("#s2").show();
            });`  NOTE every call to this will add a NEW click handler pair/one which feels bad.

Answer (score 0):

Why try to print the textarea at all? It's not really build for that. Instead maybe place the same content in a `<p>` tag, then toggle which is displayed using CSS, depending on whether screen or print? And you could even style the `<p>` to look like a form input if needed.

```css
@media screen {
  .toPrint {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media print {
  .notToPrint {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .toPrint {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea class="form-control acerto2 acerto4 area notToPrint">${Denuncia}</textarea>
<p class="toPrint">${Denuncia}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer will take your textarea content and add it to a div that is appended to the body. For the snippet, I disabled the CSS just to give an visual idea of what is happening but you will want to uncomment the CSS.

```js
let printBOX = document.querySelector(".printBOX");

function printData(el) {

  if (!printBOX) {
    printBOX = document.createElement("div");
    printBOX.setAttribute("class","printBOX");
    printBOX.setAttribute("class","print");
    document.body.appendChild(printBOX);
  }

  printBOX.innerHTML = el.value;
  //window.print();
}

let btnPrint = document.querySelector(".btn-print");

btnPrint.addEventListener("click", function() {
  printData(document.querySelector(".area"))
});
```

```css
@media print {
  .noPrint {
    /*display: none;*/
  }
}

@media screen {
  .print {
    /*display: none;*/
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea class="noPrint area">asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d asdsa d  asdsa d </textarea>
<br>
<button class="btn-print">Print</button>
```